Creating a thrown snow ball
I want to create a snowball in Blender. I've searched on YouTube, but couldn't find any tutorials on making snowball effects.
My plan was like this:
I put Fluid physics on a UV sphere and set the Flow Behavior to Geometry.
I wanted to make it splash apart as it hits the Effector and slowly drip down from it. The Viscosity is set to about 5.
The problem is, I don't know how to handle the thrown Liquid. I tried using Rigidbody, but... It doesn't seem to work well. While the UV sphere is thrown, the Liquid just flows downward. How can I create the thrown Liquid effect? Is there another way to create a snowball effect without using Fluid physics?

Hello, what about activating the Initial Velocity of the Geometry object (and give a value on Initial X, Y or Z)?

You could enable the Initial Velocity of the snowball object and set the Initial X,Y or Z to the desired value:

Result:

